# Does travel history of a minor help them when applying for a visa later as a young adult?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, b1-b2-visas

If overstaying on a visa as a minor doesn't harm a person's application later since they can't be held accountable for their parents' actions, does the opposite hold?

Can a young adult applying for a visa benefit from their travel history from when they were a minor?

If this question is too broad, I'm interested in the USA and Schengen tourism visas in particular.

Comment: You are asking for a crystal ball. Rules will change. Travel history is not so important as education and good job. Or you are asking about young adults?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I'm asking about young adults. They sometimes struggle to collect positive travel history based on questions asked here. I'll edit the question accordingly.